# ROS Answers SE migration: UR10e status

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What will is to get the status of the ur10e. When it is in some kind of stop for for instance protected stop or when the emergency button is press. I use now the `ur_modern_driver` and i subscribe to the `/robot_status` and get:

```
header: 
  seq: 6566
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs:         0
  frame_id: ''
mode: 
  val: 2
e_stopped: 
  val: 0
drives_powered: 
  val: 1
motion_possible: 
  val: 1
in_motion: 
  val: -1
in_error: 
  val: 0
error_code: 0
```

but here i can only see if it is in error not if it is a protected stop of emergency button was press. Is there a anther topic where this status is shown or?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320578/ur10e-status/) by [JoeryTemmink](https://answers.ros.org/users/40775/joerytemmink/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-08**:
Could you please reference [ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver#285](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver/issues/285)? It's almost a duplicate and provides more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> i can only see if it is in error not if it is a protected stop of emergency button was press. Is there a anther topic where this status is shown or?

that is because `robot_status` carries [industrial_msgs/RobotStatus](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/industrial_msgs/html/msg/RobotStatus.html) messages which are *generic*. "protected stop" is UR nomenclature, not generic.

What you're looking for is called `RobotMode`. It's the data packet broadcast by the UR controller that contains fields like `is_emergency_stopped` and `is_protective_stopped`. In the `ur_modern_driver`, that data is published in [ur_msgs/RobotModeDataMsg](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/ur_msgs/html/msg/RobotModeDataMsg.html) messages (on the `/ur_driver/robot_mode_state` topic):

> ```
> uint64 timestamp
> ```

```
bool is_robot_connected
bool is_real_robot_enabled
bool is_power_on_robot
bool is_emergency_stopped
bool is_protective_stopped
bool is_program_running
bool is_program_paused
```

Please note that by integrating these topics (and messages) into an application, you embed an (implicit) assumption into your code that makes it less reusable / reconfigurable (namely: you're checking for the status of a Universal Robot).

---

Edit:

> But if i read this correctly is that there is no topic where the RobotMode data is published to.

As noted in the [readme](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver/blob/195f5e937af6459f8808df3f021923614e761413/README.md) (in the *Improvements* section) the `ur_modern_driver` publishes `RobotModeDataMsg`s on the `/ur_driver/robot_mode_state` topic.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoeryTemmink](https://answers.ros.org/users/40775/joerytemmink/) on 2019-04-08**:
yes that is what i mean! But if i read this correctly is that there is no topic where the RobotMode data is published to.

**Comment by [JoeryTemmink](https://answers.ros.org/users/40775/joerytemmink/) on 2019-04-08**:
Ah now i know why i coun't find it! The RobotMode is on the master branche of the ur_modern_driver (at GitHub). But i use the kinetic_devel and there is no RobotMode. I use the kinetic-devel instead of the master becouse when i use the master with the robot it stops at every waypoint and with the kinetic-devel it wil go with a smooth motion.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-08**:\

> The RobotMode is on the master branche of the ur_modern_driver (at GitHub). But i use the kinetic_devel and there is no RobotMode.

No, it should be there on `kinetic-devel` as well. But you need to be running a recent version. If you've checked out `ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver` *before* April the 4th then you need to fetch the latest version, as it was only added recently.

If you can show us the output of `git rev-parse HEAD | cut -c1-8` (after `cd`ing to the `ur_modern_driver` directory in your workspace) then we can see whether your clone is up-to-date.

**Comment by [JoeryTemmink](https://answers.ros.org/users/40775/joerytemmink/) on 2019-04-09**:
Thanks that was the problem i had the version before 4th of April.